# Нужно создать триггер для блокирования ввода выбора материала, который отсутствует

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql, триггер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребят, у меня есть таблицы: "Склад" (Код, Материал FK, Количество), "Материал" (Код, Название, Тип_материала) и "Расходные_материалы" (Код, Склад FK, Количество, Дата_расхода)

Они связаны. Мне нужно создать триггер, который будет блокировать ввод в таблицу "Расходные_материалы" и выводить исключение, если значение в "Количество" этой таблицы превышает значение "Количество" в таблице "Склад".

Перепробовал множество вариантов, не выходит. Делаю на Postgres. Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На mysql это делается достаточно просто, нужно при вставке (обновление таблицы) выполнять субзапрос с проверкой значения и если условие не удовлетворяет, выкидывать исключение.
Пример на mysql 5.5
Структура тестовых таблиц:

```
# расходные материалы
CREATE TABLE `consumables` (
    `storage_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `count` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`storage_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

# склад
CREATE TABLE `storage` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `count` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Теперь создадим триггер с проверкой кол-ва позиций, алгоритм как ты и описал, вставляем позицию, проверим кол-во если столько нет, выкидываем ошибку

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER count_check
BEFORE INSERT ON consumables 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE storage_count INT DEFAULT 0; 
  SELECT count FROM storage AS S WHERE S.id = NEW.storage_id INTO storage_count; 
  IF(storage_count < NEW.count) THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'На складе нет столько позиций';
  END IF;
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Добавим тестовую позицию на склад:

```
INSERT INTO `storage` (`id`, `name`, `count`) VALUES ('1', 'test', '10');
```

Теперь при добавление любой позиции для которой на складе меньшее кол-во будет вылетать ошибка:

```
INSERT INTO `consumables` (`storage_id`, `count`) VALUES ('1', '100');
```

[image: На складе нет столько позиций]

Для PG может отличатся логика создания триггера, но идея такая же, если будет нужно напишу и для него.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Выручили. Переписал для Postgres, работает!